# How to resolve proxy issue in owasp dependency check?

Tags: security, owasp, maven-dependency-check-plugin

I ran the below command to run the dependency check under a proxy server.

```
./dependency-check.sh \
     --scan test/sample.jar \
     --project test_owasp \
     --out test/output \
```

It gives me the following output:

```
[DependencyCheck] [ERROR] Unable to download meta file: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-modified.meta
[DependencyCheck] org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.exception.UpdateException: Unable to download meta file: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-modified.meta
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.NvdCveUpdater.getMetaFile(NvdCveUpdater.java:347)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.NvdCveUpdater.getUpdatesNeeded(NvdCveUpdater.java:385)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.NvdCveUpdater.update(NvdCveUpdater.java:122)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.doUpdates(Engine.java:936)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.initializeAndUpdateDatabase(Engine.java:737)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.analyzeDependencies(Engine.java:667)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.App.runScan(App.java:254)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.App.run(App.java:186)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.App.main(App.java:81)
[DependencyCheck] Caused by: org.owasp.dependencycheck.utils.DownloadFailedException: Download failed, unable to retrieve 'https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-modified.meta'
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.utils.Downloader.fetchContent(Downloader.java:131)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.update.NvdCveUpdater.getMetaFile(NvdCveUpdater.java:340)
[DependencyCheck]   ... 8 common frames omitted
[DependencyCheck] Caused by: org.owasp.dependencycheck.utils.DownloadFailedException: Error downloading file https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-modified.meta; unable to connect.
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.utils.HttpResourceConnection.obtainConnection(HttpResourceConnection.java:238)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.utils.HttpResourceConnection.fetch(HttpResourceConnection.java:138)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.utils.Downloader.fetchContent(Downloader.java:126)
[DependencyCheck]   ... 9 common frames omitted
[DependencyCheck] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
[DependencyCheck]   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[DependencyCheck]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
[DependencyCheck]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
[DependencyCheck]   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
[DependencyCheck]   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[DependencyCheck]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
[DependencyCheck]   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
[DependencyCheck]   at org.owasp.dependencycheck.utils.HttpResourceConnection.obtainConnection(HttpResourceConnection.java:178)
[DependencyCheck]   ... 11 common frames omitted
[DependencyCheck] [INFO] Skipping RetireJS update since last update was within 24 hours.
[DependencyCheck] [WARN] Unable to update 1 or more Cached Web DataSource, using local data instead. Results may not include recent vulnerabilities.
[DependencyCheck] [ERROR] Unable to continue dependency-check analysis.
[DependencyCheck] [ERROR] One or more fatal errors occurred
[DependencyCheck] [ERROR] Unable to download meta file: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-modified.meta
[DependencyCheck] [ERROR] No documents exist
```

It was not able to download the Metadata thru' proxy, eventhough I passed the below parameters with command.

```
--proxyserver sample.proxy.com \ 
--proxyport 1234
```

Could anyone help me on resolving this issue, please!!

Comment: Did the solution proveded work for you? In my case it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a Maven Project and adding **owasp dependency check** dependency code in pom.xml, I was able to run owasp dependency check along with the smooth download of resources (nvd-cve's). Before running add the jars to scan, in src/main/resources location.

pom.xml:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check</artifactId>
    <version>99.0.0.0.0</version>
    <name>OWASP_Dependency_Check</name>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </project>
```

Run the following command:

```
mvn clean install  org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:check -DscanSet.fileSet=['src/main/resources/']
```

Regarding Proxy - I had to update proxy in two settings.xml.
1) .m2/settings.xml
2) apache-maven-3.6.3/conf/settings.xml